# Lists - pairing up

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two (fairly large) lists of equal length & would like to pair them up.

eg - from:

```
a = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}};
b = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};
```

I would like to get:

```
{{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{0, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{0, 3}, {1, 4}}}
```

I have looked at various thing like Tuple, but can't see a way of doing it efficiently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Transpose` is convenient for this:

```
Transpose[{a, b}]

(* Equivalently: *)
{a, b}\[Transpose]
(* {{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{0, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{0, 3}, {1, 4}}} *)
```

You can make `\[Transpose]` with <kbd>Esc</kbd>tr<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Or you can use [`MapThread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapThread.html):

```
MapThread[List, {a, b}]
```

[`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html) works too:

```
Thread[{a, b}]
```

So which one to use? They are all pretty fast, but `Transpose` is in my experience the fastest and if you happen to have `l={a, b}` as a packed array it will remain packed which is preferable.

Comment: @ ssch, Great! - Thank you - I can't get over the speed at which some of these questions are answered on this site! :)

Comment: Incidentally, thanks also for the unintended help with (*...*) - little things like this help to clean up my code nicely :)

Comment: @martin No problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Another options not using `Transpose` is `Flatten`, just need to use `{2}` for second argument

```
Flatten[{a, b}, {2}]
```

But it looks like `Transpose` is still faster:

```
a = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {5000000}];
b = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {5000000}];
First@Timing[Flatten[{a, b}, {2}]]  (* 0.234002 *)
First@Timing[Transpose[{a, b}]]  (* 0.156001*)
```

Comment: I can't find the `{2}` type of specification in the documentation, is it equivalent to `{{2}}`?

Comment: @ssch good question, I can't find it either, I just assumed it will work since this is a common level specification used by many other similar commands. So, I would have to say yes, but I am no expert in Mathematica specs, may be someone would know. At least it does give same results for this example. i.e `{2}` or `{{2}}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Partition[Riffle[a,b],2]

{{{0, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{0, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{0, 3}, {1, 4}}}
```

On my machine this approach (0.51 secs) is faster than `Flatten` (0.66 secs) but slower than `Transpose` (0.37 secs) for the 5 million Random datasets.